# Adding condition to Observable (rx-java)

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I'm still relatively new to Rx-java and reactive programming in general.

Heres my current code. What it does right now:

1. Check device if data is present
2. If present, fetch it
3. If not present, fetch from server

   ```
   Observable<PastPaper> observable = Observable.concat(
           helper.loadFromDevice(params),
           helper.loadFromServer(params))
           .takeFirst(pastPaper -> pastPaper != null);

   observable.subscribe(....);
   ```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Check device if data is present
2. If present, fetch it
3. If not present, check if internet connection is active
4. If internet connection is active fetch from server

How may I add the check for internet connectivity according to the steps above? (already have a method).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Side question: Can my code above be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `switchOnError` so that the `loadFromServer` call will be ignored if it fails. For sanity's sake you might log any error from the server as a warning:

```
Observable<PastPaper> observable = Observable.concat(
    helper.loadFromDevice(params),
    helper.loadFromServer(params)
          .doOnError(e -> log.warn(e.getMessage()))
          .switchOnError(e -> Observable.empty())
    .takeFirst(pastPaper -> pastPaper != null);
```

Otherwise if you would like to use your internet connection active observable (an `Observable<Boolean>` say) use `flatMap`:

```
Observable<PastPaper> observable = Observable.concat(
    helper.loadFromDevice(params),
    internetAvailable
        .filter(x -> x)
        .flatMap(x -> helper.loadFromServer(params)))
    .takeFirst(pastPaper -> pastPaper != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Artificial runnable sample: start with local, switch to remote if local is empty, return default value if network is not available

```
        Observable<Integer> local = Observable.fromCallable(() -> 1);
        Observable<Integer> remote = Observable.fromCallable(() -> 2);
        Observable<Boolean> hasInternet = Observable.fromCallable(() -> true);
        Integer noLocalNoInetVal = 42;

        Observable<Integer> localOrEmpty = local.filter(localVal -> localVal != null);
        Observable<Integer> remoteWithInet = hasInternet
                                               .filter(inetAvailable -> inetAvailable)
                                               .flatMap(__ -> remote);

        Observable<Integer> localOrRemote = localOrEmpty.switchIfEmpty(remoteWithInet)
                                                 .firstOrDefault(noLocalNoInetVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the most simple way it would be use switchIfEmpty

```
    Observable<PastPaper> observable = Observable.just(helper.loadFromDevice(params))
                  .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(helper.loadFromServer(params)))
                  .subscribe(....);
```

You have here other examples of how works  https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/combining/ObservableSwitch.java